# Suppose $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow X$ is continuous and $f(0) = f(1)$ , then is there a continuous $g: S^1 \rightarrow X$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow X$ is continuous and $f(0) = f(1)$ , then is there a continuous $g: S^1 \rightarrow X$ that is in a sense a parametrization of the loop f using the circle instead of the interval?

The obvious thing to try is that there is a non-continuous bijection from the $S^1$ to $[0, 1)$, and then take that to the image of $f$ in $X$. Since $f(0) = f(1)$, this map from the circle is surjective on the path $f$. But how do we show this is continuous?

Comment: To state your question more explicitly: you want $f(t)=g(e^{2i\pi t})$. That is: $f$ factors continuously through $t\longmapsto e^{2i\pi t}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to use the universal property of a quotient map. If $q\colon X\to Y$ is a quotient map and $Z$ is any topological space then if $f\colon Y\to Z$ is a function, we have that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f\circ q$ is continuous.

Can you think of a map $g\colon S^1\to X$ such that if $q\colon[0,1]\to S^1$ is given by $q(\theta)=e^{i\theta}$, then $g\circ q=f$?

The universal property is actually more often given in the even more ready-to-use form as the following: if $g\colon X\to Z$ is continuous and if for all $x,y\in X$ such that for $x\sim y$ we have $g(x)=g(y)$, then there exists a unique continuous map $f\colon X/{\sim}\to Z$ such that $g=f\circ q$. The only work you would need to do here is to then show that $[0,1]/0\sim 1\cong S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT.** How could you parametrize the circle (obviously not using $[0,1]$ in any way). For example, how would you parametrize the unit circle using $\cos$ and $\sin$? Does that make the necessary continuous mapping using $f$?

Comment: What do you mean not using [0, 1] in any way? I thought a parametrization of something (like the circle) means a continuous mapping from [0, 1] to the circle.

Comment: @ewewe It depends on how you define parametrization (it could be over any $[a,b]$). The idea is to create a parametrization of the circle that is continuous, then in a sense, stitch the mappings all together. This could probably also be shown using lifts as well. More details have been given by Daniel. I preferred to leave it as more a general hint for thought.